# 2-morphisms for 2-category: don't understand how to draw

Tags: tikz-pgf, xy-pic

Can't understand how to draw it.
[image]

Answer (score 9):

This is almost in the [manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/tikz-cd/tikz-cd-doc.pdf#page=8).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
  A \arrow[r, bend left, "f", ""{name=U,inner sep=1pt,below}]
  \arrow[r, bend right, "g"{below}, ""{name=D,inner sep=1pt}]
  & B
  \arrow[Rightarrow, from=U, to=D, "\alpha"]
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Answer (score 8):

I'll toss my hat into the ring as well - even though both `@egreg` and `@HenriMenke` have great answers, I think plain old `TikZ` is a good alternative, because the code is a bit easier to parse. We declare each node, give it a name (in the parenethesis `()`, the label is in curly braces `{}`), and then draw arrows between the nodes. Here's the code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (a) at (0,0) {$A$};
\node (b) at (1.5,0) {$B$};
\draw[->] (a) to [bend left] node[scale=.7] (f) [above] {$f$} (b);
\draw[->] (a) to [bend right] node[scale=.7] (g) [below] {$g$} (b);
\draw[-{Implies},double distance=1.5pt,shorten >=2pt,shorten <=2pt] (f) to node[scale=.7] [right] {$\alpha$} (g);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

An obvious downside is trying to replicate `\Rightarrow` with `double`, but I think it's not too big a deal, and the code is fairly easy to adjust. We also have to shorten then ends of the middle arrow so it doesn't overlap with the other arrows (done with `shorten >` for one and `shorten <` for the other end). Here's the result:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Section 25 of the reference manual. You can use

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[all,2cell,cmtip]{xy}
\UseTwocells

\begin{document}

\[
\xymatrix{
  A \rtwocell^f_g{\alpha} & B
}
\]

\end{document}
```

However, going `tikz-cd` is something I'd recommend.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility is `pst-node`, and its `psmatrix` environment. It can be compiled with `pdflatex` if you load `auto-pst-pdf` and compile with the `--enable-write18` switch (MiKTeX), or `-shell-escape` (TeX Live, MacTeX):

```
\documentclass[border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node,amsmath, latexsym}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}

 $ \begin{psmatrix}[colsep = 1.5em,nodesepA=2pt, nodesepB=1pt, shortput=nab, labelsep=2pt, arrowinset=0.2]
 [name=A] A & \Downarrow & [name=B] B
 \ncarc[arcangle=35]{->}{A}{B}^{f}
 \ncarc[arcangle=-35]{->}{A}{B}_{g}
\end{psmatrix} $

\end{document}
```

[image]